# Flask- Cannot read or write to file

Tags: amazon-ec2, flask

I am using AWS EC2 to host a Flask application and I am trying to read and write to a text file when the user submits a form using the open() function. When the form is submitted I am getting the error:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

I am not sure why this error is happening.

The code that does this is:
`@app.route("/submit", methods=["POST"])`

```
def submit(): 
    file = open("settingsfile.txt", "w") 
    file.close()
```

Comment: This question is like black box. Post some code here. Also, check logs of AWS

Comment: The code that does this is:
`@app.route("/submit", methods=["POST"])`  
`def submit():`
 `file = open("settingsfile.txt", "w")`
 `file.close()`

Comment: Also how do I check the logs?

Comment: First check your logs , check this tutorial how to check it : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html . Then tell us what error you get on your logs after you submit

Comment: I am not using elastic beanstalk so that method doesn't work for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188970/allow-write-to-file-on-ubuntu-server

Comment: Please run the server in `debug` mode: `app.run(debug=True)` and share the details on the error page.